# how to create timer in rails? and how to save this time in database in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timer

i have a `task` model in my rails app. a user will create the task. and  after creating the task, while starting the task a user will start the timer. and after the task is over a user will stop the timer. and i want to record the time taken to implement that task by this timer. what should be the datatype to record this duration? here i want to have two buttons start and stop. and upon the stop button click, i want to record the duration and want to save in the database. in what way i can implement this `timer`in Rails. is there any gem for this kind of functionality?

Comment: https://github.com/mauriciopasquier/jquery-countdown-rails

Answer (score 0):

One option could be to save `start time` and `end time` by `ajax` calls on `start` and `stop` buttons press, and calculate the time spent by the difference of the start and end time on the go.